# How to find .css file location according to class name(under div tag) in notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++

**.html**

```
<ul class="post-categories">
 <li>
  <a href="category/fruits-fresh/index.html" rel="category tag">FruitFresh</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to find which css file include "post-categories" class inside the folder structure. Normally I had to waste most time for this.Is there  simple way to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the following steps

1. Press **Ctrl+F** to open the Find and replace tool.
2. Open **Find in files tab**. Fill in the **Find what:** field and select the directory for the search (folder with your site files, template package, theme folder, etc.)
3. Click **Find All**

Check the [Reference](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-use-the-find-in-files-feature-in-notepad.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio? If so, ctrl + f and search for it in the entire solution.

Comment: Oh notepad++. I see the tag now.

Answer (score 0):

In `Notepad++` press `Ctrl+f` and it will open the window or go to `Search` -> `Find`, and click `find all in all opened documents`.

this will search in all opened files with notepad, so if you have multiple `.css` files it will search in all of them.

EDIT:

`Ctrl+shift+f` or`Search  -> find in files` and then at `directory` you select your folder.
[Check this site for example](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/09/16/use-notepad-to-find-text-in-all-files-of-a-folder/)

Comment: Without open all css file can I find what I need. Because there is many css file in my folder